# SQL Server : dynamic order by sort by asc

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I have a SQL query that I'm running with a conditional order by statement.

I'm trying to order by desc with nulls last, however my query returns the results not in asc order.

Here's an example:

```
DECLARE @Sort varchar(300);
SET @Sort = 'UngradedDescription asc'

SELECT 
    [UngradedDescription]
FROM 
    [dbo].[CardListing_Staging]
ORDER BY
    CASE 
        WHEN @Sort = 'UngradedDescription asc' 
            THEN ((CASE WHEN UngradedDescription IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))
    END
```

These are the results I get:

[image]

How can I get them in asc order 02... 04... 06... nulls?

Answer (score 0):

After some testing I found out it's multiple case statements

```
declare @Sort varchar(300);

set @Sort = 'UngradedDescription asc'
SELECT 
[UngradedDescription]
    
FROM [dbo].[CardListing_Staging]
 
order by 
            
CASE 
WHEN @Sort = 'UngradedDescription asc' then ((CASE WHEN UngradedDescription IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))
END,
CASE 
WHEN @Sort = 'UngradedDescription asc' then UngradedDescription
END
```